# what is it called if numbers $a$ and $b$ are such that their sum is equal to unity

Tags: terminology

Question:

Is there a way to definitionally describe rational numbers $a$ and $b$ when $a+b=1$?

Answer:

My guess is that $a$ and $b$ may be defined as `unitary additive complements,' but this is just a guess.

Comment: Formulas were invented to avoid such linguistic abominations, imho. What's wrong with $a+b=1$?

Comment: The word "complement" is reasonable, especially if they are between $0$ and $1$, but it's not exactly a standard term, except maybe in the context of talking about probabilities, where this would naturally be of interest.

Comment: I would tend to just refer to $b$ as "$1-a$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same way that the error function, erf($x$), and the complementary error function, erfc($x$), sum to one (i.e., erf($x$) + erfc($x$) = 1) [1], so too then are $a$ and $b$ `complementary` under addition if $a + b = 1$.

[1]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Complementary_error_function